# Google Tag Manager Custom Template Syntax issue

Tags: google-tag-manager

Is there a way to use try-catch syntax in GTM custom variable templates. It runs on sandboxed JavaScript and even having an empty Code tab with just:

```
try {
} catch (e) {
}
```

gives error:

1 Error(s) parsing the input:
missing ';' at '{'
Offending token '' at 1,4

What am I missing here? Isn't this the most basic syntax and it isn't supported?

Comment: Unfortunately, try-catch is not supported in Custom templates as far as I know. I think you will need to validate your code's execution in a different way.

Comment: Well that's a bummer because I need to deal with an exception that might be thrown from a JavaScript standard API and handle logic in a different way if that exception occurs. Is there a way to catch an exception without catch statement?